# Lost connection to vmware player VM when connect to VPN

Tags: vpn, vmware-player

I have one CentOS VM installed on local VMWare player with NAT. The IP address is "192.168.126.128" and host computer IP address is "192.168.126.1". I can reach it and work on it. But when I connect to company's VPN with cisco anyconnect, I immediately lose the connection to the VM.

I compared the route. Before VPN, there is a route:

```
IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         10.0.0.1         10.0.0.3     10
         10.0.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.0.3    266
         10.0.0.3  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.3    266
       10.0.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.3    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
    **192.168.126.0    255.255.255.0         On-link          10.0.0.3     11**
  192.168.126.255  255.255.255.255         On-link          10.0.0.3    266
    192.168.163.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.163.1    276
```

But it disappeared when I connect VPN with cisco anyconnect. Manually add with 'route -p add' doesn't work.
It worked before but after a VPN update it doesn't work now.
Can you please kindly share your experience about this? Thanks

Comment: Change to another IP address doesn't work too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change the subnet to a subnet not covered by VPN route list to fix this issue. I found it is not easy to change it. I had to install workstation and use the vmnetcfg.exe to update the configuration first(then remove).